# Верна ли пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Чтобы уберечь покупателей от принятия неправильных решений в таких ситуациях, агентство обратилось за помощью к специалистам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предложении желательно изменить порядок слов:

*Чтобы **в таких ситуациях** // уберечь покупателей от принятия неправильных решений, агентство обратилось за помощью к специалистам.*

**Пояснение**. Обстоятельственный оборот "в таких ситуациях" в конце придаточного предложения плохо вписывается в интонационную структуру СПП, да и по смыслу его можно отнести к главной части. Поэтому оборот лучше переставить.

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении (СПП).